# Passing a property name to a generic method

Tags: c#, generics

I wrote this so far:

```
public static bool DuplicateValuesExist<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    var hashset = new HashSet<T>();
    return list.Any(t => !hashset.Add(t));
}
```

I want to make it a bit more advanced so that I can pass a list of my custom class and a `property` name on that custom class so it would be able to create the hash only by using **that specific property** I pass to it.

For example if I have a `class` of **Teacher** and it has a **LastName** `property` on it, I want it to be able to calculate it only or that **LastName** property.

Comment: I would recommend making it a use an `Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>` so you could do something like `var b = (List<Person> variable).DoesDuplicateExist(p => p.LastName)`.

Comment: You could just do `teacherList.Select(t => t.LastName).DuplicateValuesExist()`.

Comment: Although basic on your current method you could just write `people.GroupBy(p => p.LastName).Any(p => p.Count() > 1)`.

Comment: @juharr oh yes haha  good suggestion actually.

Comment: @ErikPhilips GroupBy is greedy, it looks lazy but for it to finish, it must enumerate the whole thing.

Comment: yeah didn't want to use GroupBy...it is a bit slower

Comment: The question wasn't about performance so trying to determine if it's usual-able would require more information.  Obviously a list of 1,000 who cares.